# Spring Boot Webservice from WSDL not working

Tags: web-services, spring-boot

I am using spring boot and web service from existing wsdl. I am getting error on server side while accessing request from jmeter.

Please help me to resolve this error.

[image]

**Error:**

```
2014-11-11 14:24:15.157 [http-nio-9016-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.s.SoapMessageDispatcher - Endpoint invocation resulted in exception - responding with Fault
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://services.cablevision.com/IOEquipmentServices", local:"getInventoryStatusRequest"). Expected elements are <{http://services.cablevision.com/IOEquipmentServices/}getInventoryStatusRequest>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:681) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:247) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:242) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:109) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1086) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:510) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:492) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:60) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:163) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:229) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:112) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:354) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:337) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor$Jaxb2SourceCallback.domSource(AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.java:248) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xml.transform.TraxUtils.doWithSource(TraxUtils.java:84) ~[spring-xml-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.unmarshalFromRequestPayload(AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.java:137) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor.java:50) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.getMethodArguments(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:321) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.invokeInternal(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:285) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.invoke(AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.java:55) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:236) [spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:176) [spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:89) [spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:61) [spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:293) [spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863) [spring-webmvc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837) [spring-webmvc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1033) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar:8.0.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar:8.0.8]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.8.jar:8.0.8]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_11]
2014-11-11 14:24:15.158 [http-nio-9016-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.server.MessageTracing.sent - Sent response [SaajSoapMessage {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Fault] for request [SaajSoapMessage {http://services.cablevision.com/IOEquipmentServices}getInventoryStatusRequest]
2014-11-11 14:24:15.208 [http-nio-9016-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.t.h.MessageDispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

**WebServiceConfig.java**

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
  }

  @Bean(name = "IOEquipmentServices")
  public Wsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition() {
    SimpleWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("Schema/WS/IOEquipmentServices.wsdl"));
    return wsdl11Definition;
  }
}
```

**IOEquipmentServiceEndPoint.java**

```
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;

import com.cvc.provision.appdev.external.ws.object.GetInventoryStatusRequest;
import com.cvc.provision.appdev.external.ws.object.GetInventoryStatusResponse;
import com.cvc.provision.appdev.external.ws.object.GetWorkOrderDetailsRequest;
import com.cvc.provision.appdev.external.ws.object.GetWorkOrderDetailsResponse;

@Endpoint
public class IOEquipmentServiceEndPoint {
  private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://services.cablevision.com/IOEquipmentServices";



  @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getWorkOrderDetailsRequest")
  //@PayloadRoot(namespace = "{http://services.cablevision.com/IOEquipmentServices/}getInventoryStatusRequest", localPart = "")
  @ResponsePayload
  public GetWorkOrderDetailsResponse getWorkOrderDetailsRequest(@RequestPayload GetWorkOrderDetailsRequest request) {
    GetWorkOrderDetailsResponse response = new GetWorkOrderDetailsResponse();
    System.out.println("method invoked with wsdl approach1");
    return response;
  }

  @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getInventoryStatusRequest")
  //@PayloadRoot(namespace = "{http://services.cablevision.com/IOEquipmentServices/}getWorkOrderDetailsRequest", localPart = "")
  @ResponsePayload
  public GetInventoryStatusResponse getInventoryStatusRequest(@RequestPayload GetInventoryStatusRequest request) {
    GetInventoryStatusResponse response = new GetInventoryStatusResponse();
    System.out.println("method invoked with wsdl approach1");
    response.setCallStatus(true);
    return response;
  }
}
```

**IOEquipmentServices.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s0:definitions name="IOEquipmentServices" targetNamespace="http://services.cablevision.com/IOEquipmentServices" xmlns="" xmlns:s0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:s1="http://services.cablevision.com/IOEquipmentServices" xmlns:s2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
  <s0:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://services.cablevision.com/IOEquipmentServices" xmlns:s0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:s1="http://services.cablevision.com/IOEquipmentServices" xmlns:s2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://services.cablevision.com/IOEquipmentServices" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xsd:element name="getBoxInfoData">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="boxMAC" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="serialNumberSmartCard" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getBoxInfoDataResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="serialNumberCard" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="ip" type="xsd:string">
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="mac" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="mfg" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="serialNumberBox" type="xsd:string">
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="type" type="xsd:string">
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="success" type="xsd:boolean">
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="failDescription" type="xsd:string">
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="foo">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="in" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="fooResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="out" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getNetworkDeviceInfoRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="infoIn" type="tns:CtNetworkDeviceInfo"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getNetworkDeviceInfoResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="infoOut" type="tns:CtNetworkDeviceInfo">
                </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="failureDescription" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:attribute name="success" type="xsd:boolean"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:complexType name="CtNetworkDeviceInfo">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="ip" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" name="infoItemList" type="tns:CtInfoItem"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name="CtInfoItem">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="value" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:element name="getMACAttributesRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="infoIn" type="tns:CtMACAttributesInfo"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getMACAttributesResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="infoOut" type="tns:CtMACAttributesInfo">
                </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="failureDescription" type="xsd:string">
                </xsd:element>
          </xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:attribute name="success" type="xsd:boolean"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:complexType name="CtMACAttributesInfo">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="mac" type="xsd:string">
            </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" name="infoItemList" type="tns:CtInfoItem"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:element name="showProvSwapButtonRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="techId" type="xsd:int"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="showProvSwapButtonResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="showButton" type="xsd:boolean">
                </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="failureMessage" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:attribute name="success" type="xsd:boolean"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getWorkOrderDetailsRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="accountNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="techId" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getWorkOrderDetailsResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="failureMessage" type="xsd:string">
                </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="openWIPWorkOrder" type="xsd:boolean">
                </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="openTCWorkOrder" type="xsd:boolean">
                </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="openSROWorkOrder" type="xsd:boolean">
                </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="validTechId" type="xsd:boolean">
                </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="installAllowed" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="swapAllowed" type="xsd:boolean"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:attribute name="success" type="xsd:boolean"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getInventoryStatusRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="accountNumber" type="xsd:string">
                </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="boxSerialNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getInventoryStatusResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="failureMessage" type="xsd:string">
                </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="boxStatusValid" type="xsd:boolean">
                </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="callStatus" type="xsd:boolean">
                </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="boxFoundInventory" type="xsd:boolean">
                </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="inventoryStatusFlag" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:attribute name="success" type="xsd:boolean"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getBoxInfoDataByBoxSerialRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="boxSerialNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getBoxInfoDataByBoxSerialResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="mfg" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="serialNumberBox" type="xsd:string">
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="type" type="xsd:string">
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="success" type="xsd:boolean">
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="failDescription" type="xsd:string">
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
  </s0:types>
  <s0:message name="getBoxInfoDataRequest">
    <s0:part element="s1:getBoxInfoData" name="getBoxInfoDataRequest"/>
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="getBoxInfoDataResponse">
    <s0:part element="s1:getBoxInfoDataResponse" name="getBoxInfoDataResponse"/>
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="fooRequest">
    <s0:part element="s1:foo" name="fooRequest"/>
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="fooResponse">
    <s0:part element="s1:fooResponse" name="fooResponse"/>
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="getNetworkDeviceInfoRequest">
    <s0:part element="s1:getNetworkDeviceInfoRequest" name="getNetworkDeviceInfoRequest"/>
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="getNetworkDeviceInfoResponse">
    <s0:part element="s1:getNetworkDeviceInfoResponse" name="getNetworkDeviceInfoResponse"/>
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="getMACAttributesRequest">
    <s0:part element="s1:getMACAttributesRequest" name="getMACAttributesRequest"/>
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="getMACAttributesResponse">
    <s0:part element="s1:getMACAttributesResponse" name="getMACAttributesResponse"/>
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="showProvSwapButtonRequest">
    <s0:part element="s1:showProvSwapButtonRequest" name="showProvSwapButtonRequest"/>
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="showProvSwapButtonResponse">
    <s0:part element="s1:showProvSwapButtonResponse" name="showProvSwapButtonResponse"/>
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="getWorkOrderDetailsRequest">
    <s0:part element="s1:getWorkOrderDetailsRequest" name="getWorkOrderDetailsRequest"/>
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="getWorkOrderDetailsResponse">
    <s0:part element="s1:getWorkOrderDetailsResponse" name="getWorkOrderDetailsResponse"/>
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="getInventoryStatusRequest">
    <s0:part element="s1:getInventoryStatusRequest" name="getInventoryStatusRequest"/>
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="getInventoryStatusResponse">
    <s0:part element="s1:getInventoryStatusResponse" name="getInventoryStatusResponse"/>
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="getBoxInfoDataByBoxSerialRequest">
    <s0:part element="s1:getBoxInfoDataByBoxSerialRequest" name="getBoxInfoDataByBoxSerialRequest"/>
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="getBoxInfoDataByBoxSerialResponse">
    <s0:part element="s1:getBoxInfoDataByBoxSerialResponse" name="getBoxInfoDataByBoxSerialResponse"/>
  </s0:message>
  <s0:portType name="IOEquipmentServices">
    <s0:operation name="getBoxInfoData">
      <s0:input message="s1:getBoxInfoDataRequest"/>
      <s0:output message="s1:getBoxInfoDataResponse"/>
    </s0:operation>
    <s0:operation name="foo">
      <s0:input message="s1:fooRequest"/>
      <s0:output message="s1:fooResponse"/>
    </s0:operation>
    <s0:operation name="getNetworkDeviceInfo">
      <s0:input message="s1:getNetworkDeviceInfoRequest"/>
      <s0:output message="s1:getNetworkDeviceInfoResponse"/>
    </s0:operation>
    <s0:operation name="getMACAttributes">
      <s0:input message="s1:getMACAttributesRequest"/>
      <s0:output message="s1:getMACAttributesResponse"/>
    </s0:operation>
    <s0:operation name="showProvSwapButton">
      <s0:input message="s1:showProvSwapButtonRequest"/>
      <s0:output message="s1:showProvSwapButtonResponse"/>
    </s0:operation>
    <s0:operation name="getWorkOrderDetails">
      <s0:input message="s1:getWorkOrderDetailsRequest"/>
      <s0:output message="s1:getWorkOrderDetailsResponse"/>
    </s0:operation>
    <s0:operation name="getInventoryStatus">
      <s0:input message="s1:getInventoryStatusRequest"/>
      <s0:output message="s1:getInventoryStatusResponse"/>
    </s0:operation>
    <s0:operation name="getBoxInfoDataByBoxSerial">
      <s0:input message="s1:getBoxInfoDataByBoxSerialRequest"/>
      <s0:output message="s1:getBoxInfoDataByBoxSerialResponse"/>
    </s0:operation>
  </s0:portType>
  <s0:binding name="IOEquipmentServicesPort" type="s1:IOEquipmentServices">
    <s2:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <s0:operation name="getBoxInfoData">
      <s2:operation soapAction="http://services.cablevision.com/IOEquipmentServices"/>
      <s0:input>
        <s2:body use="literal"/>
      </s0:input>
      <s0:output>
        <s2:body use="literal"/>
      </s0:output>
    </s0:operation>
    <s0:operation name="getBoxInfoDataByBoxSerial">
      <s2:operation soapAction="http://services.cablevision.com/IOEquipmentServices"/>
      <s0:input>
        <s2:body use="literal"/>
      </s0:input>
      <s0:output>
        <s2:body use="literal"/>
      </s0:output>
    </s0:operation>
    <s0:operation name="foo">
      <s2:operation soapAction="http://services.cablevision.com/IOEquipmentServices"/>
      <s0:input>
        <s2:body use="literal"/>
      </s0:input>
      <s0:output>
        <s2:body use="literal"/>
      </s0:output>
    </s0:operation>
    <s0:operation name="getNetworkDeviceInfo">
      <s2:operation soapAction="http://services.cablevision.com/IOEquipmentServices"/>
      <s0:input>
        <s2:body use="literal"/>
      </s0:input>
      <s0:output>
        <s2:body use="literal"/>
      </s0:output>
    </s0:operation>
    <s0:operation name="getMACAttributes">
      <s2:operation soapAction="http://services.cablevision.com/IOEquipmentServices"/>
      <s0:input>
        <s2:body use="literal"/>
      </s0:input>
      <s0:output>
        <s2:body use="literal"/>
      </s0:output>
    </s0:operation>
    <s0:operation name="showProvSwapButton">
      <s2:operation soapAction="http://services.cablevision.com/IOEquipmentServices"/>
      <s0:input>
        <s2:body use="literal"/>
      </s0:input>
      <s0:output>
        <s2:body use="literal"/>
      </s0:output>
    </s0:operation>
    <s0:operation name="getWorkOrderDetails">
      <s2:operation soapAction="http://services.cablevision.com/IOEquipmentServices"/>
      <s0:input>
        <s2:body use="literal"/>
      </s0:input>
      <s0:output>
        <s2:body use="literal"/>
      </s0:output>
    </s0:operation>
    <s0:operation name="getInventoryStatus">
      <s2:operation soapAction="http://services.cablevision.com/IOEquipmentServices"/>
      <s0:input>
        <s2:body use="literal"/>
      </s0:input>
      <s0:output>
        <s2:body use="literal"/>
      </s0:output>
    </s0:operation>
  </s0:binding>
  <s0:service name="IOEquipmentServices">
    <s0:port binding="s1:IOEquipmentServicesPort" name="IOEquipmentServicesPort">
      <s2:address location="http://cvsqcoi9:14047/ws/IOEquipmentServices"/>
    </s0:port>
  </s0:service>
</s0:definitions>
```

Comment: Namespace differs in trailing slash

Comment: Yes. That was the issue. Thanks.