# Spring 4 + Spring-boot + Web Service soap EndpointNotFound or NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-boot

I learn create Web Service  soap from [guide Producing a SOAP web service](http://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/)
When I have jar file and run main method everything is ok. I change to war file run by mvn spring-boot:run is the same.
But next i have a problem and I wont resolve it without use xml configuration (if I can) only annotation or java code

I found many similar issue but none was help 
e.g

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115205/spring-boot-with-spring-ws-soap-endpoint-not-accessable

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873168/spring-boot-webservice-from-wsdl-not-working
```

Deploy war on wildFly 8.2 after that show wsdl but nothing else.
I change

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

to

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
            SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WebServiceConfig.class);
    }
}
```

and deploy in wildFly 8.2 after that show wsdl but when put request in SoapUI

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:gs="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service">
   <soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
         <gs:getCountryRequest>
             <gs:name>Spain</gs:name>
         </gs:getCountryRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

get

```
WARN  [org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointNotFound] (default task-7) No endpoint mapping found `for [SaajSoapMessage {http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service}getCountryRequest]`
```

and clear page in soapUI

I search similar issue e.g [Endpoint not accessable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115205/spring-boot-with-spring-ws-soap-endpoint-not-accessable)

changed

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet(
        ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
}
```

to

```
@Bean
     public MessageDispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
     return new MessageDispatcherServlet();
     }
```

is the same, but when I use

```
@Bean
     public MessageDispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
     return new MessageDispatcherServlet(getContext());
     }


     private WebApplicationContext getContext() {
     AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new
     AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
     context.setConfigLocation(Application.class.getName());
     return context;
     }
```

get

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.applicationContext(Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;)Lorg/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;
```

[whole error log](http://www.speedyshare.com/PH3UD/errorLog.txt) and [whole eclipse project](http://www.speedyshare.com/7bNRk/JarTest.zip)

Comment: Your problem is, mainly your configuration. When using the `SpringBootServletInitializer` instead of using `WebServiceConfig` use `Application` as your config class just as with a normal main. You can leave the `public static main` method in btw easier for testing :).

Comment: Next to my earlier comment your pom is also flawed (Also why a build-snapshot instead of the 1.2.0 release?). You are also mixing boot versions (1.2.1 and 1.2.0 for the maven plugin, something you don't want to do). Finally you are also using a Spring Framework 4.1.2 version whereas Spring Boot depends on 4.1.3 again mixing different library versions, don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks   M. Deinum for reply it's really helpful.

First I tried use only Application class but I couldn't run server. Error in log `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xnio.SslClientAuthMode` next I found solution with create two classes `WebServiceConfig` and `Application`.After changing server started , wsdl showed for me it was good change,  therefore thank you again.

This issue is caused spring-boot bug [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/d5ad502d31335b0146e78f3380c4208a82ee360b), now I moving whole code from `WebServiceConfig` to `Application` and using the newest compile spring-boot. After that WS work good.In pom  Paste current Application class maybe someone will have the same problem.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
            SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet(
            ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "countries")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(
            XsdSchema countriesSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CountriesPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws/");
        wsdl11Definition
                .setTargetNamespace("http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(countriesSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema countriesSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("countries.xsd"));
    }

    private WebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation(Application.class.getName());
        return context;
    }
}
```